# Can't connect to remote CentOS server, possibly disk full

Tags: linux, ssh, centos5, remote-access

We have a remote server using CentOS 5 with Apache 2.2/PHP/MySQL that have crashed due to possible hard disk being full.

- Can't access WHM - giving "500 Internal Server Error"
- Can't access SSH - giving "Server unexpectedly closed connection" after inputting
  username
- Can't access FTP - giving "530 Login authentication failed"

Viewing any of our website hosted there that is using PHP gives 500 Internal Server Error.

How could I connect again to the server, delete files and reboot it? Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: do you have ilo\drac type access to this server?

Comment: that's the first time I've heard of that so its probably no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have some other remote access/management application that is actively running and capable of restoring sanity to the server, you are most likely going to need physical intervention. I would suggest giving a call to the facility where your server is located and working through diagnostics with them, or at the very least a reboot.